# SQl query to for conditional filter

Tags: sql

```
Div   Acct_Nbr  Site_Nbr Grp  Charge_Cd  
224   8001238   1         1     DSP  
224   8001238   1         1     REG  
224   8001238   1         1     REN  
761   8001238   1         3     DSP  
761   8001238   1         3     REG  
761   8001238   1         3     REN  
902     97161   1         1     BU1  
902     97161   1         1     EXY  
902     97161   1         1     FR3  
902     97161   1         1     REG
```

Above is my data set, i looking for Count  for

1. Accounts which has Charge code= 'REG' and Charge code='REN'
2. Accounts which has Charge code= 'REG' and  Charge code<>'REN'

if i keep in my where  clause for charge code condition 1 i get no result.
where i am expecting as below

```
224 8001238 1   1   REG  
224 8001238 1   1   REN  
761 8001238 1   3   REG  
761 8001238 1   3   REN
```

for Condition two in where clause i  am expecting

```
902 97161   1   1   REG
```

but i get

```
224 8001238 1   1   REG  
761 8001238 1   3   REG  
902 97161   1   1   REG
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: what query are you using? and what is you desire output?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use conditional aggregation.

For Case 1:

```
  SELECT Acct_Nbr  
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY Acct_Nbr  
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Charge_Cd = 'REG' THEN 1 END) > 0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Charge_Cd = 'REN' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Case 2 is very similar. I didn't do it because wasn't sure if you want those case separated or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, I think the issue is that a record cannot be both `Reg` and `Ren`.  That should be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM {Table} 
WHERE ChargeCd='REG' 
  and Acct_Nbr in
      (SELECT Acct_Nbm FROM {Table} WHERE ChargeCd='REN')
```

The issue is similar for your 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM {Table} 
WHERE ChargeCd='REG' 
  and Acct_Nbr NOT IN
      (SELECT Acct_Nbm FROM {Table} WHERE ChargeCd='REN')
```

Comment: Case 1 it works but for case two i am expecting just this record     902 97161   1   1   REG

Comment: @B.Sni I fixed the second one.  Now the subquery gets all of the `Acct_Nbm`  `WHERE ChargeCd='REN'` and the main query excludes results from that

Comment: If the answer solve your problem, mark is as correct using the green tick

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM {Table} 
WHERE ChargeCd='REG' 
  and Acct_Nbr in  (SELECT Acct_Nbm 
                    FROM {Table} WHERE ChargeCd='REN')

SELECT * 
FROM {Table} 
WHERE ChargeCd='REG' 
  and Acct_Nbr NOT IN (SELECT Acct_Nbm 
                       FROM {Table} WHERE ChargeCd='REN')
```

thanks Zebrainatree

Comment: In your desire output you want `REG` and `REN` rows, here you only get `REG` rows from accounts also having `REN` so two different things